# Date formatting WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datagrid

I´ve got a special problem, that first seems very easy but I don´t know any solution. 
At the moment I programm a C#-WPF-Application that makes it possible to save bookings. 
A booking also has a date, which I take from a calender. 
I save the booking to my Sql-Express Database and the value of a date is "DD.MM.YYYY", the datatype is date.

Now, I load the data into a datagrid in my application:

```
    public DataSet SaveDataToDataSet(DataSet dataset)
    {

        string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Harald\\Desktop\\Farmer´s Calc\\Programmierung\\WPF\\Finanz_WPF\\Finanz_WPF\\FarmersCalc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        string query = "select bezeichnung 'Bezeichnung', einausgaben 'Einnahmen-Ausgaben',  kostenstelle 'Kostenstelle',  datum 'Buchungsdatum', betrag 'Betrag', details 'Details' from Buchung";
        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
                query, connection);

            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            return dataset;

        }
    }
```

Strangely, the date column in the DataGrid has the format "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS", but I only want "DD.MM.YYYY"!
What I need to say is, that I don´t have Columns defined, I make it with AutoGenerateColumns=true.
Does anybody know a solution for that?

Comment: That isn´t help for me because I AutoGenerate the Columns!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid

Comment: You CAN do this without giving up auto generated columns, several of the solutions in that other answer do it.  Updated my response with one of the specific solutions that would have worked for you.

Comment: You really should adjust your answer, as the one you selected is incorrect.  Please see D..'s answer for the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "date" Sql type ends up being a DateTime in your dataset, which is why you're getting the time as well.  You'll need to define columns and specify formatting on your datagrid.

EDIT: I was mistaken about not being able to format this when auto generating columns.  As the other answer here mentions, this question: [Need to format dates in dynamically built WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid) addresses some ways to accomplish this.

Comment: But you can format the strings even with it auto generated...  using the grid.Resources... or in the code for the AutoGeneratingColumnEvent.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is just incorrect.  It CAN be done using auto-generated columns, please see the other answer for the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Indeed.  Please accept the other answer.  I was not aware of this capability.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out:

[Need to format dates in dynamically built WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid)

It involves using string formatting in your Grid resources.

There are answers in there that don't involve defining the columns... including handling it in the event for auto-generating columns.

```
private void ResultsDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        if (dataGridTextColumn != null)
        {
            dataGridTextColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:d}";
        }
    }
}
```