# c# datagrid time information

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The User inputs the time information in three different textboxes: hours/mins/seconds.
The time information is stored as total in an xml file in seconds.
The user can edit this value within a datagrid. In the datagrid the time information is shown as seconds. How can I achive that the value stored in seconds shows up in the datagrid in a more human readable format and so that the user can edit it in this way?

e.g. 4205 seconds = 1h 10m 5s

IS there a control or something similar?

Comment: you can use Timespan function to get the hours and minutes and seconds format from total seconds and take a look at this link ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/c-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseco

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET or WinForms DataGrid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to format dates in dynamically built WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always build a converter to take the bound value of seconds and spit out a desired string.