# Change type column in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
source.DataSource = dt;
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
```

In my datagrid I want to change the column type with `DateTime` to `String`, how can I do this?

---

source is

```
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource source = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the DateTime to a string? Is it because of formatting? You might achieve this by applying formatting options to the data grid on XAML-level.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `DataTemplate` for `DateTime` values ike this -

```
<DataGrid> 
    <DataGrid.Resources> 
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}"> 
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={0:d}}"  /> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </DataGrid.Resources> 
    ... 
</DataGrid>
```

refer - [Need to format dates in dynamically built WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid/849037#849037)