# DateTime just the date?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datetime

Getting abit of a problem I only know how to use DateTime to display my results like so:

```
    {

            string uri = "http://localhost:8002/Service/HireDate";
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            var staff = xDoc.Descendants("HireDate")
                .Select(n => new
                {
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireFromDate").Value), //this line
                    EndDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireToDate").Value), //this line
                    TotalDaysHired = n.Element("NumberOfDaysHired").Value,
                })
                .ToList();

            dataGrid9.ItemsSource = staff;

    }
```

However this outputs like this in my datagrid:

```
15/07/2012 00:00:00
27/07/2012 00:00:00
```

Is there a way to remove the time I just want the date?

Comment: This sounds more like a UI concern, i.e. the job of the data-grid. So: which data-grid is this? winforms? webforms? wpf? sl? xna? cf? mvc?

Comment: In that case: [Need to format dates in dynamically built WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848702/need-to-format-dates-in-dynamically-built-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to show only the `Date` part of a `DateTime` as `String`? You could use [`DateTime.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) which is most readable:

```
StartDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireFromDate").Value).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: or use `StartDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireFromDate").Value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Answer (score 4):

To get the date without time as a string, you can use `ToShortDateString` or [custom formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) provided to `ToString`:

```
var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
var shortDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Culture is considered in both `ToShortDateString` and `ToString` with a custom format (although the format is still your own). `ToShortDateString` may be more accurate with the current culture as it contains the correct format for a given culture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact function.

e.g :

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);

        var staff = xDoc.Descendants("HireDate")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(n.Element("HireFromDate").Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null), //this line
                EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(n.Element("HireToDate").Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null), //this line
                TotalDaysHired = n.Element("NumberOfDaysHired").Value,
            })
            .ToList();

        dataGrid9.ItemsSource = staff;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you're putting the date time, you can use the ToString(string format) method to set the proper format.

here you can find few format smaple:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
 StartDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireFromDate").Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
 EndDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireToDate").Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EndDate = DateTime.Parse(n.Element("HireToDate").Value).ToShortDateString()
```