# Change the format of dateTime to date only

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datetime

I have an list: "IList" that one of the filed is "dateTime". 
I added this list to dataGrid (wpf), and all the values of the filed "dateTime" show in this format: "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt", 
I want this values will show only date (date format: dd/MM/YYYY).

My code (This is not a solution):

```
        listUsers = (IList<Users>)list;
        foreach (Users user in listUsers)
        {
            user.birthday = user.birthday.Date;
        }
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = listUsers;
        listClass = "Users";
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of these answers; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+format+datetime

Comment: user.birthday.Date.ToShortDateString() is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of a date is purely a visual thing - this means that you shouldn't iterate your initial data and translate it before showing it. Especially in WPF which makes this sort of thing really easy.

You are using a DataGrid, so in the binding for the column that will show the date you simply specify a format string, as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314221/109702).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Column's binding StringFormat to "d" for the "Short date pattern". For a list of all the available dateTime formats, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" 
                            Value="{Binding JoinDate, StringFormat={}{0:d}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```